# Which decision-tree algorithm does the R package randomForest uses?

Tags: r, random-forest

`R` has a package for random forests, named `randomForest`. Its manual can be found [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf). In the manual it is not mentioned which decision-tree growing algorithm is being used. Is it the [ID3 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm)? Is it something else?

**Clarification:** I am not asking about the meta-algorithm of the random forest itself. That meta algorithm uses base decision tree algorithm for each of the grown trees. For example, in Python's scikit-learn package, the tree algorithm which is being used is [CART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_analytics#Classification_and_regression_trees) (as mentioned [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-algorithms-id3-c4-5-c5-0-and-cart)).

Comment: I've added a clarification.

Comment: The documentation references the original paper by Breiman and Cutler that describes the algorithm in detail.

Comment: I've read Breiman&Cutler's paper. They define the random forest algorithm as a meta-algorithm. See their main definition, for example (*A random forest is a classifier consisting of a collection of tree-structured classifiers*). They do give in part 4 a "simple example" using CART methodology, but in their [`fortran` code](http://stat-www.berkeley.edu/users/breiman/RandomForests/cc_examples/prog.f) (which I can't really read) they comment that their method is "*different from that in Friedman's original CART program*". I was asking about the `R` code, which is "*based on the original*".